# Visual Studio TFS checkout missing "Check out" checkout type

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

When my guys checkout a file, I would like them to lock it so others can't also make changes, I see from this post: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155783.aspx that this is possible using the `Check Out` type, however, this appears to be missing from the list of options I have available. I only have `Unchanged` and `Check In`.

I am using the free version of TFS in the cloud linked directly with VS2013.

I am using TFS Source Control and have "Enable Multiple Checkouts" disabled. I have also changed the default workspace type to server from local.

Comment: Which version control provider do you use? TFS Source Control or Git?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181419.aspx) on MSDN describes the available lock types:

> In Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2012, check-out locks are
>   generally not effective because of local workspaces (see Decide
>   between using a local or a server workspace). Specifically, check-out
>   locks are:
>
> - Not enforceable because other users might be using local workspaces.
> - Not available if you are using a local workspace.
> - Disabled if a member of the Administrators security group of your
>     team project collection has enabled asynchronous checkout for your
>     team’s server workspaces.
>
> A check-out lock prevents users who are using server workspaces from
>   checking out and making changes to the locked item in their
>   workspaces. You cannot apply a check-out lock to an item for which any
>   pending changes exist, in any workspace other than your own.

Check whether your workspace is a local one or if the administrator has set the option for asynchronous check outs. 
In my installation of Visual Studio Online I have a local workspace by default. As soon as I changed it to be stored on the server, the `Check Out` option was available.

In order to change the type of workspace, carry out the following steps:

1. In Source Control Explorer, locate the workspace drop down at the top and choose `Workspaces...`.
2. Select `Edit`, then `Advanced`.
3. Change location from `Local` to `Server`.
4. Exit the dialogs using the `Ok` or the `Close` buttons respectively.

Comment: I found this option shortly after posting and changed it to server but the option is still now available. Does it need time to propagate? Also, async is disabled.

Comment: I changed the default setting but didn't change my current workspace so all is well, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

Exclusive checkout option will not be available if the workspace Location is set to Local. If that option is needed then workspace location under workspace settings needs to be set to be “Server”.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First open team explorer settings the and go to the settings, click on source control under the Team project Collection.
[image: First Step]

then uncheck enable asynchronous checkout in server workspaces

[image: Second step]

now you can disable multi checkout

Comment: Disabling multi checkout worked for me. Must close out of VS2015 for changes to take place.